# Let $F(x,y)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t,y)dt$. Find $F_x$ and $F_y$. If $G(x)=\int_{a}^{g(x)} f(t,x)dt$, find $G'(x)$

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $$f:[a,b]\times [c,d] \to \mathbb{R}$$ is continuous and $f_{y}$ is continuous, let $$F(x,y)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t,y)dt.$$

1. Find $F_x$ and $F_y$.
2. If $G(x)=\int_{a}^{g(x)}f(t,x)dt$, find $G'(x)$

My try:

For (1) $$F(x+h,y)-F(x,y)=\int_{a}^{x+h} f(t,y)dt-\int_{a}^{x}f(t,y)dt=\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t,y)dt$$
Let $\int f(t,y)dt= H(t,y)$. Then $\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t,y)dt=H(x+h,y)-H(x,y)$. Hence $$F_x= \frac {\partial H(x,y)}{\partial x} $$. I am kind of stuck here.

$F_{y}$ is easy. $$F(x,y+h)-F(x,y)=\int_{a}^{x}\left(f(t,y+h)-f(t,y)\right) dt$$
Hence $$F_{y}=\int_{a}^{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dt $$

For (2) we have $$G(x+h)-G(x)=\int_{a}^{g(x+h)}f(t,x+h)dt-\int_{a}^{g(x)} f(t,x)dt$$
$$=\int_{a}^{g(x+h)}f(t,x+h)dt-\int_{a}^{g(x)} f(t,x+h) dt+ \int_{a}^{g(x)} f(t,x+h) dt-\int_{a}^{g(x)} f(t,x)dt$$
$$=\int_{g(x)}^{g(x+h)} f(t,x+h) dt+\int_{a}^{g(x)} \left(f(t,x+h)-f(t,x)\right)dt$$

If I let $\int f(t,x+h) dt= H(t,x+h)$. Then we have 
$$ \frac{G(x+h)-G(x)}{h}=\frac{H(g(x+h),x+h)-H(g(x),x+h)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}. \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}+\int_{a}^{g(x)}\frac{ \left(f(t,x+h)-f(t,x)\right)}{h}dt$$

Taking limit on both sides we have $$G'(x)=H'(g(x),x+h).g'(x)+\int_{a}^{g(x)}\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x}dt$$

From here How do I get thr result??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is your question? It seems you are perfectly able to compute all the derivatives!

Comment: @Siminore I need to write $H$ in terms of $f$

Answer (score 1):

Although you need to justify some passage to the limit,
$$
\partial_1 F(x,y) = \int_a^x f(t,y)\, dt,
$$
$$
\partial_2 F(x,y) = \int_a^x \partial_2 f(t,y)\, dt.
$$
Since $G(x)=F(g(x),x)$, by the chain rule
$$
G'(x)=\partial_1 F(g(x),x)g'(x) + \partial_2 F(g(x),x).
$$

Comment: How do i get them in my process?

Comment: Your $H$ is not a function of $t$...

Answer (score 1):

Just trust the force of calculus! For $F_{.1}:=F_x$ you can disregard the $y$ and differentiate the integral with respect to the upper limit:
$$F_{.1}(x,y)=f(x,y)\ .\tag{1}$$
For $F_{.2}$ you can disregard that the upper limit could be variable under other circumstances. Just differentiate under the integral sign:
$$F_{.2}(x,y)=\int_a^x f_{.2}(t,y)\>dt\ .\tag{2}$$
The function $G$ can be written in terms of $F$ as
$$G(x)=F\bigl(u(x),v(x)\bigr)$$
with $u(x):=g(x)$, $\>v(x):=x$. The chain rule gives
$$G'(x)=F_{.1}\bigl(u(x),v(x)\bigr)u'(x)+F_{.2}\bigl(u(x),v(x)\bigr)v'(x)\ .$$
Plugging in $(1)$ and $(2)$ now produces
$$G'(x)=f\bigl(g(x),x\bigr)\cdot g'(x)+\int_a^{g(x)} f_{.2}(t,x)\>dt\cdot 1\ .$$